# What are the benefits of using UIAppearance proxy instead of ordinary default values?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiappearance

Could you explain me, please, what would be the benefits of using `UIAppearance` proxy object to customize my `UIView` subclass properties instead of creating the setter methods to provide the required default values like in the following code sample:

```
@interface CustomView : UIView

+ (void)setDefaultBackgroundColor: (UIColor *)defaultBackgroundColor;

@end

@implementation CustomView

static UIColor *defaultBackgroundColor_ = nil;

- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
  self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
  if (self) {
    if (!defaultBackgroundColor_)
      defaultBackgroundColor_ = [UIColor blackColor];
  }
  return self;
}

+ (void)setDefaultBackgroundColor: (UIColor *)defaultBackgroundColor {
  defaultBackgroundColor_ = defaultBackgroundColor;
}

@end
```

In all the articles I've read about `UIAppearance` usage they say, that changing the properties of this proxy allows the instances of the class to get the same value automatically. What I cannot fully grasp is whether the proxy object is really required for this purpose? Are there any downsides of using the static vars to hold the default values in this case?

To make things more clear, I'm comparing this approach:

```
 [CustomView appearance]setBackgroundColor:someNewColor];
```

with this:

```
 [CustomView setDefaultBackgroundColor:someNewColor];
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not really the use case for `UIAppearance`. If you are writing a `UIView` subclass to only be used in a single project then just make it look the way you want.

`UIAppearance` is there for if you decide to make that subclass usable in all of your projects and it might need to be styled for each project specifically. Or if you want to use lots of instances of it without having to set the style of each individually.

Similarly to how `UILabel` works. It's a `UIView` subclass designed to be used in all sorts of different projects.

Comment: Ok, suppose, I've decided to make that subclass usable in other projects. I cannot understand, what are the benefits of using `[MyCustomView appearance]setBackgroundColor];` vs `[MyCustomView setDefaultBackgroundColor];`. In both cases we are just providing the default color for all new instances. Am I correct?

Comment: @Storix not necessarily. With `UIAppearance` protocol you gain the fine control of when to use certain styles with `appearanceWhenContainedInInstancesOf` (or whatever it's called).

Comment: Plus, I'm not sure but I don't know how subclassing your custom control would affect the styling when using your static properties vs appearance. You wouldn't easily be able to extend it I don't think?

Comment: I guess, with the help of Objective C runtime it's not difficult to implement a similar method to `appearanceWhenContainedInInstancesOf` in conjunction with static vars. But what I got about `UIAppearance` proxy is that it provides the next advantages: 1. Readability and maintainability (due to proxy design pattern we have the unified interface)  2. We don't need to reinvent the wheel :) Thanks for your answers.

Comment: @Storix yeah, you could definitely recreate it yourself. But then, UIAppearance has already been created for you :)